# ASP.Net and Stored Procedures Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is my first time in ASP.Net so...

I create a stored procedure, now I want to put this stored procedure in a GridView and do the connection, my problem is I don't how to do the connection for my stored procedures because of the StatementType. When I do Select, Update Select or Delete my StatementType go to the right action. My question is where do I have to do the connection in a Textbox, Gridview...?

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Employees 
    (@EmployeeID INT,
     @EmployeeName VARCHAR(255),
     @EmployeeUsername VARCHAR(255),
     @EmployeeEmail VARCHAR(255),
     @GroupID INT,
     @Password VARCHAR(255),
     @StatementType NVARCHAR(20) = ''
    ) 
AS 
BEGIN
    IF @StatementType = 'INSERT'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Employees]([EmployeeID], [EmployeeName], [EmployeeUsername], [EmployeeEmail], [GroupID], [Password])
        VALUES (@EmployeeID, @EmployeeName, @EmployeeUsername, @EmployeeEmail, @GroupID, @Password);
    END
    ELSE IF @StatementType = 'SELECT'
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM [Employees];
    END
    ELSE IF @StatementType = 'Update'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Employees]
        SET [EmployeeName] = @EmployeeName,
            [EmployeeUsername] = @EmployeeUsername,
            [EmployeeEmail] = @EmployeeEmail,
            [GroupID] = @GroupID,
            [Password] = @Password
        WHERE
            [EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID;
    END
    ELSE IF @StatementType = 'DELETE'
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM [Employees]
        WHERE [EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID;
    END;
END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of the ease of use of the GridView is that you do not need the Stored Procedure at all.

If your DBA only allows you access to use stored procedures then you can specify a custom SelectMethod, UpdateMethod and DeleteMethod and then manually map the values you get from the GridView to call your stored procedure but it's a very long route to doing what the GridView would have done for you pretty easily.

```
    // The id parameter name should match the DataKeyNames value set on the control
    public void EmployeeTable_UpdateItem(int id)
    {
        InvMS.Models.Employee item = null;
        // Load the item here, e.g. item = MyDataLayer.Find(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            // The item wasn't found
            ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Item with id {0} was not found", id));
            return;
        }
        TryUpdateModel(item);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Create a connection to your database here, 
            // Map the attributes to your stored procedure and call the procedure
        }
    }

    // The id parameter name should match the DataKeyNames value set on the control
    public void EmployeeTable_DeleteItem(int id)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Remember to change the name of your stored procedure as suggested by @marc_s